# Using docker-compose to start web and backend. How can I get the IP of backend from web?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, circleci

I'm stuck with docker-compose 1.5.2 as I'm using CircleCI.

```
web:
  build: .
  ports:
    - "5000:5000"
  links:
    - backend

backend:
  image: node-backend
  ports:
    - "5002:5002"
```

I'm not able to ping `backend` from the web container.
`backend` is not added to the hosts file, any idea why that is?

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
172.18.0.3      a197fe5943cb
```

docker ps tells me that the ID of the web container is: `a197fe5943cb_meshnodeweb_backend_1`

`web` needs to knows the IP of `backend`. How can I make that work using these version?

- Docker version 1.9.1
- docker-compose version 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Execute

`docker inspect <your_backend_container_id>`

It will give you a pretty long hash which will contain IP, port and many other info of your container.

**Added probable solutions**

```
docker-compose stop your_app
docker-compose rm -v your_app
docker-compose up -d
```

OR

Use compose file format **version 2**. See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ for details.

Comment: Ideally I'd like update etc/hosts on the web container with the ip of the backend. I need the web container to communicate with backend without me having to dig up the ip manually.

Comment: @martins. Updated my answer with another solution. Not really sure but could help in your case.